# how to resolve the issue(QTKit/QTKit.h not found) for MacOS sierra

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am new to Mac , my code is working fine for all OS of Mac but it's showing error while running in new OS (macOS Sierra) QTKit/QTKit.h not found.

[image: QTKit/QTKit.h not found]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I try your query on both xcode 7.3.1 and Xcode 8.2 on macOS sierra and result is
using Xcode 7.3.1 i can import `#import <QTKit/QTKit.h>`to project 
but if i create project in Xcode 8.2 then QTKit framework not show all the files that are in xcode 7.3.1 (apple removed most of QTKit's components) that's why you will not get `#import <QTKit/QTKit.h>`.

so, please create your project in xcode 7.3.1 on macOS sierra

OR

you can download the QTKit from here https://sourceforge.net/projects/qtkit/?source=typ_redirect and drag to your xcode 8.2 project and import the file `#import "QTKit/QTKit.h"`

Comment: thanks bro now I am using Xcode 7.3.1 on macOS Sierra.